# there were some errors in the query: RequestError: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sql-server-2008

i am using MS SQL Server 2008 when i run this query

```
select top 1 * from table_name where ModifiedDate='Wed Mar 16 2016 15:52:20 GMT+0530 (IST)'
```

i get this error

```
there were some errors in the query: RequestError: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

i also tried `CAST` and `CONVERT` but having same error

i am using [node mssql client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mssql)

Comment: What's your 'ModifiedDate' column datatype

Comment: @DineshDB, it's definitely of `datetime/date` and thus the said error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question directly, use this instead:

```
select top 1 * from table_name where ModifiedDate=cast('2016-03-16 15:52:20 +05:30' as datetimeoffset)
```

Now the explanation. To use timezones, you need to use datetimeoffset  - regular datetime fields don't include timezone info. So, this will work:

```
select cast('2016-7-16 15:52:20 +05:30' as datetimeoffset)
```

Using AdventureWorks2012 (this syntax will also work in sql 2008, but this is demoing how you'd write this query against the AW2012 database):

```
select top 1 * from Person.Address where ModifiedDate=cast('2002-01-04 00:00:00 +00:00' as datetimeoffset)
```

Note in this case, AW2012 uses a datetime field, but not a datetimeoffset field in this table - nevertheless, it compiles and runs.

The next example demonstrates how the timezone offset works:

```
select top 1 * from Person.Address where ModifiedDate=cast('2002-01-04 04:00:00 +04:00' as datetimeoffset)
```

This returns a value, whereas changing the offset by 1 hour returns no result. (There's one record with a ModifiedDate of 2002-01-04 00:00:00 in the table):

```
select top 1 * from Person.Address where ModifiedDate=cast('2002-01-04 04:00:00 +03:00' as datetimeoffset)
```